# remove a word from a string in lisp using regular expression

Tags: lisp, elisp, common-lisp

I have a list of string like this called F:

("hello word i'am walid" "goodbye madame") => this list contain two elements of string

and I have another list call S like this ("word" "madame") => this contain two words

now I want to remove the elements of the list S from each string of the list F and the output should be like this ("hello i'am walid" "goodbye")

i found already this function:

```
(defun remove-string (rem-string full-string &key from-end (test #'eql)
                  test-not (start1 0) end1 (start2 0) end2 key)
"returns full-string with rem-string removed"
(let ((subst-point (search rem-string full-string 
                         :from-end from-end
                         :test test :test-not test-not
                         :start1 start1 :end1 end1
                         :start2 start2 :end2 end2 :key key)))
(if subst-point
    (concatenate 'string
                 (subseq full-string 0 subst-point)
                 (subseq full-string (+ subst-point (length rem-string))))
    full-string)))
```

example: 
    (remove-string "walid" "hello i'am walid") => the output "hello i'am"

but there is a problem

example:

```
(remove-string "wa" "hello i'am walid") => the output "hello i'am lid"
```

but the output should be like this "hello i'am walid" in another word i wont the remove the exact word from the string

i have a solution is to use

```
cl-ppcre:regex-replace-all "\\s*\\bwa\\b\\s*" "ba wa walid" " ")
```

and it's great but there is one probleme
cl-ppcre:regex-replace-all "\s*\bam\b\s*" "i'am wa walid" " ")=>"i' wa walid" and it shouldn't i should have "i'am wa walid" because "i'am" is a holl word

Comment: Can you honestly reread the question yourself and say that it makes sense?  I understand language issues, but it doesn't look like you proof read this at all.  Not the best approach to getting (free) help.

Answer (score 0):

You could explicitly define your boundary characters instead of using `\b`.  Below I use whitespace, comma, begin or end of a string, or period as boundary characters.

```
(cl-ppcre:regex-replace-all 
   #?r"(\s|^|$|,|\.)(am)(\s|^|$|,|\.)" 
   "i'am wa walid" 
   #?r"\1 \3")
```

(nb: `#?\r""` comes from `cl-interpol:enable-interpol-syntax` and makes regexes easier to read)

which if we are using interpol can then also contain a splice point for a our word:

```
(let ((word "am"))
  (cl-ppcre:regex-replace-all 
     #?r"(\s|^|$|,|\.)(${word})(\s|^|$|,|\.)" 
     "i'am wa walid" 
     #?r"\1 \3")
```

Cheers, hope I am answering the correct question

Comment: That is the part in the answer above that says:  `(nb: #?\r"" comes from cl-interpol:enable-interpol-syntax and makes regexes easier to read)`.                                You can decide not use cl-interpol and double all the backslashes and use `concat` or `format` to put the word inside the regex.